# I am using hidden input type to set value and using request.getParameter() to get the value in another page but it is always returning “null”

Tags: html, sql, jsp

I am using hidden input type to set value and using request.getParameter() 
    to get the value in another page but it is always returning “null”.
    Why it is returning null value?
First Page:-

```
<%  
try{  
       Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");  
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/passkey_database","postgres","4457");  
       PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from visitor_table");  
       ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  
       ResultSetMetaData metaData=rs.getMetaData();  
       while(rs.next()){  

%>  
<tr>
 <td>  
  <input type="text" name="name" value="<%=rs.getString("visitor_name")%>">  
  <a href="permissionform.jsp"> <%=rs.getString("visitor_name")%> </a>  
</td>
<%for(int i = 2; i<=metaData.getColumnCount();i++){ %>  
<td>  
  <%= rs.getString(i)%>  
</td>
<%    }   %>     
</tr>
<%}  
}catch (Exception e) {  
e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Second Page:-

```
 <%

   String name=request.getParameter("name");
    out.println(name);
   try{
       Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/passkey_database","postgres","4457");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from visitor_table where visitor_name=?");
            ps.setString(1,name);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){

  %>
```

Comment: Is there a form arround the hidden Field?

Comment: Do not use sql directly in the jsp.

Comment: because you don't send input data to second page. for this, you need either a form or explicitly specify a url with param like this: href="permissionform.jsp?name=<%=rs.getString("visitor_name")%>"

Comment: yes there a form arround the hidden Field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this task by just a simple trick

update this line

```
<%
        String visitor_name = rs.getString("visitor_name");
        String link = "permissionform.jsp?name=" + visitor_name;
    %>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<%=visitor_name%>">  
    <a href="<%=link%>"><%= visitor_name%></a>
```

by this code you really dont need the `<input>` tag if you use this code because link is already parsed.

by this `name` value forworded will not be `null` if `visitor_name` is `not null`

Hope it helps your problem.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Session , Cookie or Context  objects to get variable in other page,or use form tag with action another page if you have `<input type="submit"/>`  tag

try this code

```
 <td> 
     <form action="permissionForm.jsp"> 
      <input type="text" name="name" 
       value="<%=rs.getString("visitor_name")%>">  
     <input type="submit" value="<%=rs.getString("visitor_name")%>"/>
    </form>    
</td>
```